# Code snippet highlighting in sublime text?(or suggest a note taking app for coding)

Tags: sql, sublimetext2, syntax-highlighting, sublime-text-plugin

I like to take notes as I learn new concepts and when learning something, say android which involves XML and JAVA  syntax and even some SQL, when I copy paste it onto a single file I want each snippet to be highlighted in a way that makes sense for that particular language...and the rest of the text remain plain much like SO itself where I can mark only the code as code....I searched online and no application meets these requirements and finally I stumbled across a sublime Text Plugin ...thing is I don't understand how to install it even after reading the instructions please guide me or if you know any other application that meets these requirements please let me know .
Thanks!

[link to the plugin](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Notes/)

Comment: Do you have Package Control installed?

Answer (score 0):

The plugin that you have linked to, "Notes", is a Sublime Text 3 plugin. It will not work on Sublime Text 2 (afaik). 
Uninstall ST2 and install ST3 and then install Package Control and then install Notes. It should install without any issue.
I'm currently using Sublime Text 3 and am able to install the plugin without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install it via Package control by pressing: cmd + shift + P. Then navigate to "install package". Once you begin typing in the package name (Notes in this example) will autocomplete then hit enter once its highlighted in the dropdown. Once installed read the Package Control Message that pops up in a new tab with instructions. These usually have key messages/directions for install or setup.

Kahlil was right when he said its not only compatible for ST2. So if it doesn't appear when you run package control thats why